# windows executable cannot find file under wsl path

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am running WSL1. I created a file in my home dir, ie `home/username`. I have a .exe file called armcc.exe in my C:\ directory. I can run something like this from the linux shell:

`/mnt/c/armcc.exe /mnt/c/test/foo.c`

However if I create a file under `/home/username`, the executable is not able to access the file, ie this command fails:

`/mnt/c/armcc.exe /home/username/foo.c`

I get an error `"no source": Error:  #5: cannot open source input file` from the compiler's executable.

This seems like the Windows filesystem cannot access the Linux side. How can I achieve this, if at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular Windows programs use the Win32 subsystem and as a result don't handle Unix paths, only Windows paths.  When you use a path to a Windows file system, it gets translated into a Windows path.

There are ways to specify file paths under WSL, [using the `\\wsl$` prefix](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/whats-new-for-wsl-in-windows-10-version-1903/).  You will likely need to use such a path for a Windows program using this Windows syntax.  However, not all Windows programs gracefully handle this path syntax, and some very much want a standard path with a drive letter, so it may not be possible to use this syntax with all programs.